# Is every packet of a hostile network flow hostile?

Tags: ids, detection, packet, intrusion, anomaly-detection

We are building a packet based anomaly detection system and I'm trying to find labeled packets.
Such dataset doesn't exist based on my search, but I can find labeled flows.

Can we say that every packet is hostile which is part of a flow that is labeled as hostile? I guess the answer is no, but I'm not sure.

For example the attacker is attacking from IP1 and the target is IP2. In a flow there are packets sent from IP2 to IP1, I assume those packets can't be considered hostile, can they? And I guess even some of the IP1 --> IP2 packets are benign, even if they are part of a hostile flow.

Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: I think that you are making some unstated assumptions that would affect any conclusions. And from a taxonomy perspective, you need to be clear about what *you* classify as "hostile" for your own purposes. Packets from IP2 could be considered hostile if IP1 triggered a reflection attack, or used IP2 as a pivot, or ... So, how are you defining "hostile"?

Comment: How you define your taxonomy also affects whether things like simple ACKs from the target are hostile in your classification scheme.

Comment: *Hostile Packet* seems like an unworkable definition. An ARP query for an IP is perfectly normal, but is it hostile from one source but not from another? Is a person walking into a store and looking around hostile? What about if the person is casing the store for a possible robbery? Intrusion detection typically keys on specific designated signatures and patterns. I think you need to work on what you are trying to accomplish.